# How to compare OracleTimeStamps

Tags: c#, oracle, timestamp, compare

I have two byte[] (like this { 0, 0, 0, 0, 52, 246, 141, 6 }) that represent two Oracle's timestamps.
How do I know which one is older?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10593/sqlqr06002.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the binary timestamp to `Int64` and then compare the corresponding `long` values:

```
var value = new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 52, 246, 141, 6 };
long timestamp = BitConverter.ToInt64(value, 0);
```

The bigger the `long` value, the more recent the timestamp. I haven't used Oracle but I would guess this represents the number of ticks since the [Epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29).